# eigenvectors of non-symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices

If I have a non-symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ (real entries), and I multiply all the points on a unit circle (centred at the origin) by $A$, the unit circle will be transformed to a regular ellipse, however the eigenvectors of $A$ will generally not coincide with the ellipse axes and will probably not even be orthogonal. Is there a way to change A into a symmetric matrix whose eigenvectors represent the ellipse axes? A simple example using a  $2 \times 2$ matrix would be appreciated eg $a_{11} = 1, a_{12} = 3, a_{21} = 2, a_{22} = 4  $

Answer (score 2):

The axes of the ellipse are the [left singular vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $A$. They are therefore the eigenvectors of $S=AA^T$ and $P=S^{1/2}$. The matrix $P$ can be obtained from the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) $A=PU$. Since $S$ and $P$ share the same set of eigenvectors, you may calculate either one of them.